# Executing rebar3 throwing escript exception

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, elixir, rebar3

**Environment:**

```
1. Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
2. Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.6.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] 
Eshell V10.6.4
3. Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.6.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] 
Elixir 1.9.1 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 22)
```

---

**Exception:**

```
escript: exception error: undefined function rebar3:main/1
in function  escript:run/2 (escript.erl, line 758)
in call from escript:start/1 (escript.erl, line 277)
in call from init:start_em/1 
in call from init:do_boot/3
```

---

See the answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **[Solved]**
Installing from the source [erlang](https://www.erlang.org/patches/otp-26.1), [rebar3](https://github.com/erlang/rebar3/releases/download/3.21.0/rebar3).

Steps:

1. `sudo apt-get purge erlang elixir`
2. `sudo apt autoremove`
3. Remove rebar3, erlang, and elixir related files if any.
4. Download Erlang.
5. Unzip it.
6. Go to unziped folder.
7. Execute: **sudo su -**
8. Execute: `./configure && make && make install`
9. Download rebar3, and make sure it supports OTP-{**your_version**}
10. `chmod u+x rebar3`
11. `./rebar3 local install`
12. `mv rebar3 /usr/local/bin/`
13. Execute `rebar3 --version` from any dir.

---

From what I see, the root causes are in bold.

1. Lack of privileges.

```
meaning
sudo su -
./configure && make && make install

and
sudo ./configure && make && make install
is not the same.
```

2. Version compatibilities.